# c++ Property Implementation wrt getter for struct type cannot be converted automatically?

Tags: c++, properties, getter

im trying to implement Property on c++ and here's my code:
Property.hpp

```
#ifndef __VIOLET_PROPERTY_H__
#define __VIOLET_PROPERTY_H__

class IProperty
{
protected:
    virtual void init_properties() = 0;
};

#define READ_ONLY 1
#define WRITE_ONLY 2
#define READ_WRITE 3

template <typename Container, typename ValueType, int nPropType>
class property
{
public:
    property()
    {
        m_cObject = NULL;
        Set = NULL;
        Get = NULL;
    }

    //-- Set a pointer to the class that contain the property --
    void setContainer(Container* cObject)
    {
        m_cObject = cObject;
    }

    //-- Set the set member function that will change the value --
    void setter(void (Container::* pSet)(const ValueType& value))
    {
        if ((nPropType == WRITE_ONLY) || (nPropType == READ_WRITE))
            Set = pSet;
        else
            Set = NULL;
    }

    //-- Set the get member function that will retrieve the value --
    void getter(ValueType(Container::* pGet)())
    {
        if ((nPropType == READ_ONLY) || (nPropType == READ_WRITE))
            Get = pGet;
        else
            Get = NULL;
    }

    //-- Overload the = operator to set the value using the set member --
    ValueType operator =(const ValueType& value)
    {
        assert(m_cObject != NULL);
        assert(Set != NULL);
        (m_cObject->*Set)(value);
        return value;
    }

    //-- Cast the property class to the internal type --
    operator ValueType()
    {
        assert(m_cObject != NULL);
        assert(Get != NULL);
        return (m_cObject->*Get)();
    }

private:
    //-- Pointer to the module that contains the property --
    Container* m_cObject;
    //-- Pointer to set member function --
    void (Container::* Set)(const ValueType& value);
    //-- Pointer to get member function --
    ValueType(Container::* Get)();
};

#endif
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Property.hpp"
using namespace std;

struct B
{
    B(int _v) { value = _v; }
    int value = 0;

    operator int() {
        return value;
    }
};

class A
{
    B value = 10;
    void setValue(const B& _value)
    {
        value = _value.value;
    }
    B getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
public:
    A() {
        Value.setContainer(this);
        Value.setter(&A::setValue);
        Value.getter(&A::getValue);
    }
    property<A, B, READ_WRITE> Value;
    operator B() {
        return value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a = A();
    B b = a.Value;
    int num = 1 + (B)a.Value + b;
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

my question is that why i need to forcely set `(B)` for `a.Value` but cannot use implicit conversion like `1+a.Value`
i've already set convert function for getter and why i cannot get a `ValueType` type from it?

```
    operator ValueType()
    {
        assert(m_cObject != NULL);
        assert(Get != NULL);
        return (m_cObject->*Get)();
    }
```

nevertheless, if i just cannot achieve it, does it mean that i'll get more cost for explicit conversion?
appreciate any help.

Comment: `#define __VIOLET_PROPERTY_H__` that identifier is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it yourself, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Comment: @eerorika no i think it is just my diy character string or is there any link for its reservation?

Comment: I cannot remember the section name exactly, but it's something like 'reserved names" in the C++ standard.

Comment: @liiight Names starting with double underscores are reserved for implementations as per the C++ standards (all of them)

Comment: @DanielJour thanks i haven't noticed it

Comment: @eerorika thanks i'll check it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two user defined conversions:

- `a.Value` is a `property<A,B,READ_WRITE>`.  It has a user defined conversion operator to `B`.
- `B` has a user defined conversion operator to `int`.

They cannot form a so called implicit conversion sequence and therefore you need to explicitly convert `a.Value` to `B` first. From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1) zero or one standard conversion sequence;
>
> 2) **zero or one** user-defined conversion;
>
> 3) zero or one standard conversion sequence.

---

> nevertheless, if i just cannot achieve it, does it mean that i'll get more cost for explicit conversion?

No, an optimizing compiler will have no issues turning this into a direct access of the encapsulated integer.

---

You can however use a conversion operator template to get what you need:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
struct Inner {
    int value = 42;
    operator int() const {
        return value;
    }
};
 
struct Outer {
    Inner thing;
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const {
        return thing;  // One implicit conversion sequence here, 
                       // with one user defined conversion (from Inner to int)
    }
};
 
 
int main() {
    Outer b;
    int answer = b; // Another implicit conversion sequence here,
                    // with one user defined conversion (from Outer to int)
    std::cout << answer << std::endl;
}
```

Using a similar template on your `A` will get you what you want.

Comment: why `a.Value` is `A` type but not `property`, if it's `property`, then the getter must return a 
templated `ValueType` object which in this case must be `B`

Comment: hm .. wait; I might have mixed something up here.

Comment: Fixed it to match the question's types/expressions better

Comment: thanks for pointing out this, thats exactly what i need

Comment: Glad I could help you.  If your question is solved by my answer please consider marking it as "accepted" (https://stackoverflow.com/tour)